# VB.NET 2.0 - StackOverflowException when using Thread Safe calls to Windows Forms Controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, thread-safety, .net-2.0, stack-overflow

I have a Windows Forms app that, unfortunately, must make calls to controls from a second thread. I've been using the thread-safe pattern described on the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx. Which has worked great in the past.

The specific problem I am having now: I have a WebBrowser control and I'm attempting to invoke the WebBrowser.Navigate() method using this Thread-Safe pattern and as a result I am getting StackOverflow exceptions. Here is the Thread-Safe Navigate method I've written.

```
Private Delegate Sub NavigateControlCallback(ByRef wb As WebBrowser, ByVal url As String)

Private Sub AsyncNavigate(ByRef wb As WebBrowser, ByVal URL As String)
    Try
        If wb.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim callback As New NavigateControlCallback(AddressOf AsyncNavigate)
            callback(wb, url)
        Else
            wb.Navigate(url)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Is there a Thread-Safe way to interact with WinForms components without the side effect of these StackOverflowExceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
If wb.InvokeRequired Then
    Dim callback As New NavigateControlCallback(AddressOf AsyncNavigate)
    callback(wb, url)
Else
```

On the second line of the If block, you're *just calling AsyncNavigate again*. Directly. Resursively. With no marshalling to a UI thread. You should be using `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`:

```
If wb.InvokeRequired Then
    Dim callback As New NavigateControlCallback(AddressOf AsyncNavigate)
    wb.BeginInvoke(callback(wb, url))
Else
```

(Side-note: please don't swallow exceptions like that...)

Comment: Well that definitely stopped the StackOverflow exceptions, but now the navigate never actually occurs. I'll go do some more research on this. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @LamdaComplex: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the `wb.Navigate` call itself, to see whether that gets invoked? If you want the background thread to wait until the callback has happened, you should use `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`, of course.

Comment: @LamdaComplex `but now the navigate never actually occurs` this is were exceptions come into play and you are just ignoring them.

Comment: Thanks Jon, your solution works great, but once again it proves I need to read those MSDN articles more carefully. And as for the new problem: a small typo on my part was the problem. The WebBrowser reference I was passing into the method was actually the wrong one, which is why I didn't see the navigate happening as I expected.